# Is my PSU ATX 4-pin connector reversed from the standard?

Tags: power-supply, connector, atx

I just got an [EVGA 750 GQ](https://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/210-GQ-1000-0850-0750-0650.pdf) power supply. The manual mentions that it includes an ATX 20+4 pin motherboard cable. However, the 4-pin connector appears to reverse the pinouts from the 4-pin plug on the motherboard.

Here is a picture of the male EVGA 750 GQ connector:
[image]

Here is the male connector on the old power supply:
[image]

You can see that the pins are reversed compared to the EVGA power supply.

Here’s the female connector on the motherboard:
[image]

Wikipedia seems to indicate that the connector on the old power supply is the standard: See picture from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX
[image]

I was wondering if anyone might know why the pins might be reversed on this power supply? Is there a name for this “reversed connector”? And is there a way to adapt the connector to make it compatible with my motherboard?

...

**Update:**

This is a Lenovo TS140 branded box that I am attempting to upgrade. It has a 4-pin power connector and a 14-pin power connector.

[image]

I was planning to adapt the 20-pin power cable to the 14-pin plug with [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IB5YCNG), which specifically mentions the TS140 motherboard.

As for the 4-pin, it actually does fit, if you tilt it at a right angle. Upon further research, there are [similar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-reviews/R31PED73LT9VVA/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B017ROGC12) [comments](https://forums.evga.com/m/tm.aspx?m=2743202&p=1) about the connector not fitting, but being able to rotate it.

I have not yet tested this configuration, as I am waiting on the 20-pin-to-14-pin adapter, and I so am unsure about whether the system will power on.

Is the 4-pin connector on the Lenovo motherboard proprietary? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Judging by the Google Image results for "ATX 20+4 pin", I'd say your old power supply has the wrong plug. Is this a custom desktop or a branded box you are trying to upgrade?

Comment: The picture of the female connector on the motherboard appears to be of the wrong connector. The correct one is actually part of a single 24 pin connector on the motherboard, i.e. on the motherboard it is a 12x2 connector, which from the power supply is a 10x2 + 2x2 connector that gets married together.

Comment: Please, using better lighting against a neutral background, and your camera's 'macro' setting, photograph the 4-pin power supply connector next to the 20-pin connector, with the latches on each connector up, and then click on [edit] and upload the new picture. Then, take a picture of the connector on _your_ motherboard, and upload that as well. What _is_ the make and model of the motherboard, anyway?

Comment: I added additional information to the question. I will improve the photography shortly. Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further research, I have discovered that that Lenovo motherboard and 14-pin power supply is totally proprietary.

I will do more research later to discover the best way to adapt the standard ATX 20+4 power supply to the proprietary Lenovo plug.

Comment: Just to follow up, I was able to adapt the ATX 20+4 pin standard connector to the 14-pin proprietary Lenovo connector using this adapter: https://www.amazon.com/NEORTX-Power-Supply-Adapter-Lenovo/dp/B00WE5KSFQ I was also able to connect a 12-volt supply from the PSU (labelled as CPU) to the 4-pin female connector on the motherboard pictured above. This had an 8-pin connector on the PSU, but the cable was split into 2 4-pin connectors. Plugging in one of these 4-pin connectors into the 4-pin female connector on the motherboard worked perfectly. The computer boots and seems fully operational.